# A very silly riddle with bad rhymes

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Don't judge too hard.

It took me about a minute to make up these bad rhymes for a very silly riddle.

It is really silly =) I'll try better next time.

**UPDATE**

I added a little hint to the rhymes

> I can be old, I can be new,
>   I can be false, I can be true,
>   On camping trips I visit you,
>   Near the fireplace at night,
>   The time for me is usually right.
>
> Now who am I or *what* am I?
>   The answer is for you to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to Jannis' answer, are you a:

> Scary story?

As

> There are classics, there are new ones, most are made-up monster tales, some are real-life unexplained mysteries, and they're often told around campfires late at night

Comment: Damn) I thought it would take longer)

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> Campfire song?
>  This is pretty obvious, so i think it's wrong

Because:

> true, false, old and new are attributes a song can hold
>  and it's usually played on camping trips at nights near the fireplace

Comment: Damn) close, very close) i thought of something a bit different as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> a friend?

I can be old, I can be new,

> Old friends and new friends

I can be false, I can be true,

> [False friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend) and true friends

On camping trips I visit you,

> Trips generally spent with friends and family

Near the fireplace at night,
The time for me is usually right.

> People gather around a fire and make friends.

Comment: =) Also close, i guess my riddle has too many right answers) I thought of one which wqas a bit different, when i made the rhymes up

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> A joke

As people say they are old, new, right or wrong.
And also tend to say it's always a good time for one.

Comment: But can rot13(n wbxr) be false or true ? =)